# Detect [i] value

Tags: javascript, yql

I am trying to make a condition where [i] is a value for data.length, the problem is that everything works okay when there are more than 1 value, but when theres only 1 value, the script doesnt work.

```
        out.href = data[i].href;
        out.innerHTML = data[i].alt;
        out.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

Explanation:
When data.length is more than 1, the result will be object1.href, object2.href, etc.
But when the returned query is only of 1 value, i want it to write just "object.href" without the [i] in it, because this works with yql and when yql returns only 1 object, the object number is direct, doesnt have any value. Instead of object1.href, there will only be object.href but the script keeps placing the value in object[i].href thus failing when only 1 result is returned.

Is there any if...else method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `count` value which is returned with every YQL response.

```
if (o.query.count == "1") {
    data = [data];
}
```

Comment: Thats it, many thanks salathe, i have been wondering around loop circles and if...else mazes and that did the trick!